# How to figure out PPM or Pixel Per Meter on Box2D?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, pixel, meter

The unitScale on my tiled map renderer is 1/16f.

My orthographic camera has the following dimensions: (16f,9f).

Does that mean that my pixel per meter is 16? I'm drawing MapObjectPolygons from my object layer but they are not scaled down like my map, should I divide their proportions by the Pixel Per Meter?

Thanks, I've been reading dozens of articles and questions on the internet but I don't understand this concept still.

Answer (score 0):

"Does that mean that my pixel per meter is 16?"
No take a step back because your `Orthographic` camera is set up wrongly. Unlike the `Perspective` camera, it needs the absolute viewport size (e.g. the screen) not a ratio. So you need to set according to the screenWidth and screenHeight.

(From the below link)

```
float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
```

Have a look here
https://gamefromscratch.com/libgdx-tutorial-11-tiled-maps-part-2-adding-a-sprite-and-dealing-with-layers/